# Substract the result for level time0 from the results from all other levels, for each id

Tags: r

I want to substract the result for level time0 from the results from all other levels, for each id.

```
id <- rep(1:4,each=4)
time <- rep(c(0,5,10,15),4)
a <- c(34,56,67,35)
b <-c(56,78,23,90)
c <- c(23,89,67,78)

df <- data.frame(id,time,a,b,c)
df
   id time  a  b  c
1   1    0 34 56 23
2   1    5 56 78 89
3   1   10 67 23 67
4   1   15 35 90 78
5   2    0 34 56 23
6   2    5 56 78 89
7   2   10 67 23 67
8   2   15 35 90 78
9   3    0 34 56 23
10  3    5 56 78 89
11  3   10 67 23 67
12  3   15 35 90 78
13  4    0 34 56 23
14  4    5 56 78 89
15  4   10 67 23 67
16  4   15 35 90 78
```

I started like this but it feels there must be a more efficient way. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
for( i in 1:length(unique(df$id))){
  df_id <- df[df$id==i,]
  for(j in 2:length(time)){
    test <- t(df_id[,-1])
    test[,c(2:4)]-test[,1]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(a:c, ~. - .[time == 0])) %>%
  ungroup

#      id  time     a     b     c
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     0     0     0     0
# 2     1     5    22    22    66
# 3     1    10    33   -33    44
# 4     1    15     1    34    55
# 5     2     0     0     0     0
# 6     2     5    22    22    66
# 7     2    10    33   -33    44
# 8     2    15     1    34    55
# 9     3     0     0     0     0
#10     3     5    22    22    66
#11     3    10    33   -33    44
#12     3    15     1    34    55
#13     4     0     0     0     0
#14     4     5    22    22    66
#15     4    10    33   -33    44
#16     4    15     1    34    55
```

Using `time == 0` would work if it is guaranteed that every `id` has exactly 1 value of `time = 0`. If for some `id`'s there is no row for `time = 0` or have more than one row with `time = 0` then probably using `match` is better option.

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(across(a:c, ~. - .[match(0, time)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapply` in `by`.

```
vc <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
by(df, df$id, \(x) {x[-1, vc] <- mapply(`-`, x[-1, vc], x[1, vc]);x}) |>
  do.call(what=rbind)
#      id time  a   b  c
# 1.1   1    0 34  56 23
# 1.2   1    5 22  22 66
# 1.3   1   10 33 -33 44
# 1.4   1   15  1  34 55
# 2.5   2    0 34  56 23
# 2.6   2    5 22  22 66
# 2.7   2   10 33 -33 44
# 2.8   2   15  1  34 55
# 3.9   3    0 34  56 23
# 3.10  3    5 22  22 66
# 3.11  3   10 33 -33 44
# 3.12  3   15  1  34 55
# 4.13  4    0 34  56 23
# 4.14  4    5 22  22 66
# 4.15  4   10 33 -33 44
# 4.16  4   15  1  34 55
```

If id==0 position is not consistent, you need to formulate more verbose:

```
{x[x$time != 0, vc] <- mapply(`-`, x[x$time != 0, vc],  x[x$time == 0, vc]);x}
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), time = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15, 
0, 5, 10, 15, 0, 5, 10, 15), a = c(34, 56, 67, 35, 34, 56, 67, 
35, 34, 56, 67, 35, 34, 56, 67, 35), b = c(56, 78, 23, 90, 56, 
78, 23, 90, 56, 78, 23, 90, 56, 78, 23, 90), c = c(23, 89, 67, 
78, 23, 89, 67, 78, 23, 89, 67, 78, 23, 89, 67, 78)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```